# Install SSL Certificate in WorldClient, MDaemon 12

Tags: ssl, https

I have an issue after I installed the SSL Certificate in WorldClient, MDaemon 12.

I followed the [link](http://www.altn.com/Support/KnowledgeBase/KnowledgeBaseResults/?Number=KBA-01844) in installing the SSL, SSL installation was fine. Then, I followed the [link](http://www.altn.com/Support/KnowledgeBase/KnowledgeBaseResults/?Number=KBA-02202) to use the SSL in WorldClient. I use 888 for TCP port and 443 for https port.

When I call the webmail (http://mail.mydomain.com.sg:888) in browser, it opens properly. But, if https://mail.mydomain.com.sg:888, Secure Connection Failed error message is shown.

Any Ideas, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
If you read all instruction from the link you given in your post carefully until finished, you'll get the answer.

> Note: MDaemon will only display certificates that have private keys
>   using the Personal Information Exchange format (PKCS #12). If your
>   imported certificate does not appear in the list then you may need to
>   import a *.PEM file, which contains both a certificate key and private
>   key. Importing this file using the same process outlined above will
>   convert it to the PKCS #12 format.

You should [make a PKCS#12](http://help.globalscape.com/help/secureserver3/Generating_a_PKCS_12_private_key_public_certificate.htm) file from generating the (certificate) .csr and private key (.key) you have. If you on windows, install the openssl first on your PC. After successful generate the PKCS#12 file, follow the instruction again to install the SSL certification on MDaemon.

If you success, you'll see the certificate appear in the MDaemon.
Remember to restart your server or webserver to apply the changes.

Regards